# SSIS Package Read data from text file and pass as parameter value into the stored procedure for update

Tags: ssis

I am new in SSIS development. Can anyone let me know the steps how to perform following task.
I need to read data from text file one by one record and pass as parameter value to stored procedure. Stored procedure perform if record exists then update if not then insert.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you're completely new to SSIS, have a look here - it starts out with a tutorial on retrieving data from a text file:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

If you're still struggling to get things working after working through tutorials or examples elsewhere, then I'd suggest updating the question with what you've tried, what's going wrong, and perhaps a screenshot or two if they'd help explain the problem.

Comment: So far I developed the stored procedure which is working fine after passing parameter. Now I need to create the package to read data from text file as stored procedure parameter value. I can read records from flat file source but then I am stuck what I have to do. As per logic I should have to start loop to read record from flat file and pass the value to stored procedure as parameter to execute. I am not sure what transformation have to use. I tried OLE DB Destination but wont work.

Comment: Try EXECUTE SQL transformation.